# How can I get a list of Sheet2!A2:A cell values where (Sheet2!B2:B= "Yes") and (Sheet1!B2:B less than 200)

Tags: google-sheets

How can I get a list of Sheet2!A2:A cell values where (Sheet2!B2:B= "Yes") and (Sheet1!B2:B less than 200) (ignoring values that are in Sheet1!A2:A but not in Sheet2!A2:A)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TPXl4qnUcufrbBZ-mEoz6LPEiL_XtXw374r0IDITudg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. There is one formula in A1 (currently highlighted in bright green):

`=ArrayFormula({"Matches YES and <200"; IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!B2:B="Yes",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:B,2,FALSE),9^9)<200))})`

This formula produces the header (which you can change as you like within the formula) and all results.

`FILTER` will return any elements of Sheet2!A2:A that match two conditions:

1.) the corresponding cell in Sheet2!B2:B is "Yes"

2.) the value beside a `VLOOKUP` of that Sheet2!A:A element within Sheet1!A2:B is less than 200.

There are two `IFERROR` wraps. The innermost one will assign `9^9` (i.e., a ridiculously high number) to any element of Sheet2!A2:A that is not found at all within Sheet1. This will rule it out as being <200. (NOTE: If you want to adapt this formula to return matches where Sheet1!B2:B is *greater than* a certain number, just delete the `9^9` from this `IFERROR` clause.

The outermost `IFERROR` wrap will simply bypass the error that would result if there are zero matches to the `FILTER` and will instead return null.